# Serve multiple domains on one ip and one port

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost, multiple-domains

I want to serve multiple domains on my CentOS server.
I run servers on http.
Now I want to run these servers on https.

I written ssl.conf like this.

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
  ServerName example.com:443
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/two.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/two.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
  ServerName two.example.com:443
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/two
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? You need to be more detailed. Do you receive an error?

Comment: On webbrowser, https://example.com works properly.
But https://two.example.com display example.com website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it works fine.

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
  ServerName example.com:443
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/two
  ServerName two.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```